# Replacing UIViews when screen rotates in the same View Controller

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, nib, autorotate

I have never done this before - changing a ViewController´s UIView like this, so although it seems to be working perfectly I am unsure if this is a good idea - if it could lead to any major bugs. It uses Storybards but the `viewLandscape` is loaded from `nib`

So I start off retaining a pointer to the current view in ViewDidLoad, I assume that the first view when `viewDidLoad` is portrait, how can I be absolutely sure of this? then I initiallize the landscape view from nib.

```
// Assumes UIView loaded at start is portrait
self.viewPortrait = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.viewPortrait = self.view;

UIView *landscapeView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LandscapeView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"view %@", landscapeView);
self.viewLandscape = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:landscapeView.bounds];
self.viewLandscape = landscapeView;
```

Now, I set which view to show according to the interface direction, pretty simple! but is it anything I should be aware of? One thing more, I have a label on the landscape view, how to I get a pointer to that label in this `ViewController` (Pointer from the nib to the View Controller for the storyboard view)

```
-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    NSLog(@"will rotate");
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            self.view = self.viewPortrait;
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            self.view = self.viewLandscape;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to have a different view controller for horizontal and present that view controller from your vertical VC with a cross-fade. There's more info about this in the [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html) under "Creating an Alternate Landscape Interface".

Comment: Thanks! I were having problems with my solution cause I had a two views in a tab bar controller and when I went to the other view, rotated the device and go back to this view - the wrong view would be loaded. And Apple has made it near impossible to progmatically change the direction in iOS 6. I spent several hours trying to figure out to do it before i gave up.